# How to calculate monthly sales for an aging report

Tags: mysql

It's fairly simple, I have a table that contains invoice lines, including invoice number, item number, and quantity.  I want to look at the last 18 months and figure out how many of a particular item we've sold in 30 day increments.

`select
invlines.`i-no`,
@days_sold := DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), invlines.`inv-date`) AS days_sold,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 1 AND 30, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month1,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 31 AND 60, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month2,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 61 AND 90, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month3,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 91 AND 120, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month4,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 121 AND 150, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month5,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 151 AND 180, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month6,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 181 AND 210, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month7,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 211 AND 240, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month8,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 241 AND 270, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month9,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 271 AND 300, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month10,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 301 AND 330, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month11,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 331 AND 360, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month12,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 361 AND 390, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month13,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 391 AND 420, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month14,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 421 AND 450, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month15,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 451 AND 480, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month16,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 481 AND 510, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month17,
SUM(IF(@days_sold BETWEEN 511 AND 540, invlines.`qty`, 0)) as Month18
from invlines
where invlines.`i-no`="10 37148" and invlines.`inv-date`between (NOW() - INTERVAL 540 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY invlines.`i-no``

What I'm getting is a quantity in the Month18 column, but nothing in any of the other Month columns.  I'm using a very similar solution in another report and it works correctly, but can't figure out why this one isn't working.

Comment: Hm, no thanks. Maybe see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, but seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you at something like this

```
CREATE TABLE `invlines` (
`i-no` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`inv-date` datetime NOT NULL,
`qty` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `invlines` (`i-no`, `inv-date`, `qty`) VALUES
('10 37148', '2019-07-07 08:00:00', '1'),
('10 37148', '2019-07-07 07:00:00', '1'),
('10 37148', '2019-06-01 08:00:00', '1'),
('10 37148', '2019-06-02 08:00:00', '1'),
('10  37148', '2019-05-02 08:00:00', '1'),
('10 37148', '2019-05-01 08:00:00', '1'),
('10 37148', '2019-04-07 08:00:00', '1'),
('10 37148', '2019-04-02 08:00:00', '1'),
('10 37148', '2019-03-02 08:00:00', '1'),
('10 37148', '2019-03-01 08:00:00', '1');

Select `i-no`,Sum(month1),SUM(month2),SUM(month3) From
(Select `i-no`,
  CASE WHEN ( DATEDIFF(Now(), `inv-date`) > 0 
         and DATEDIFF(Now(), `inv-date`) < 30) then SUM(qty) END  as month1,
  CASE WHEN ( DATEDIFF(Now(), `inv-date`) >= 30 
         and DATEDIFF(Now(), `inv-date`) < 60) then SUM(qty) END  as month2,
  CASE WHEN ( DATEDIFF(Now(), `inv-date`) >= 60 
         and DATEDIFF(Now(), `inv-date`) < 90) then SUM(qty) END  as month3
 From invlines
 Group by floor(datediff(Now(), `inv-date`) / 30)) a
 Group by `i-no`;
```

result

```
i-no    Sum(month1)     SUM(month2)     SUM(month3)
10 37148    2                2              2
```

Comment: The inclusion of '-' in table / column identifiers is unwise